# How to save multiple fields using 'onSave ()' function in react-editext?

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently using this plugin for my react application: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-editext.

I have multiple fields:

```
<EdiText
  value={contact.addressLine1}
  type="text"
  onSave={handleSave('addressLine1')}
  onCancel={(e) => setEditing(v => !v)}
  inputProps={{
    placeholder: 'Address Line 1',
  }}
/>
<EdiText
  value={contact.addressLine2}
  type="text"
  onSave={handleSave('addressLine2')}
  onCancel={(e) => setEditing(v => !v)}
  inputProps={{
    placeholder: 'Address Line 2',
  }}
/>
```

With a save handle

```
const handleSave = (e) => value => {
  setContact({...contact, [e]: value})
};
```

But, I need to be able to save all fields with one button.

Now, if these were controlled form fields, I would be able to grab the value, and submit. But they're not as there is no `onChange` event.

Any ideas?

Comment: i dont quite visualize what you are trying to achieve. how does your code behaviour now

Comment: Instead of having an edit, save and cancel button for each field, I just want one save button that will save all fields. I've created a sandbox similar to what I want: https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-firefly-e6i85

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find in the plugin a possibility to do that. I suggest that you use a form with refs to achieve what you want.
here is an example code

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [editing, setEditing] = useState(true);
  const [contact, setContact] = useState({
    addressLine1: "Address 1",
    addressLine2: "Address 2"
  });
  const [adress1, setAdress1] = useState("adress 1");
  const [adress2, setAdress2] = useState("adress 2");

  const form = useRef(null);

  const handleSave = () => {
    const adresses = {
      addressLine1: form.current["adress1"].value.toString(),
      addressLine2: form.current["adress2"].value.toString()
    };
    setContact(adresses);
    console.log(contact);
  };
  const handleEdit = () => {
    const edit = editing;
    setEditing(!edit);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form ref={form}>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={adress1}
          name="adress1"
          onChange={e => setAdress1(e.target.value)}
          disabled={editing}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          value={adress2}
          name="adress2"
          onChange={e => setAdress2(e.target.value)}
          disabled={editing}
        />
      </form>
      <button onClick={handleSave}>save</button>
      <button onClick={handleEdit}>edit</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

explanation

- I used state variable `editing` to make the fields editable or not on button edit click
- I used a state variable for each field and used the react onChange function to save the value of each field when it changes.
- on save button click the values of all fields states get saved to `contact` state

you can change the code to make it suitable for your needs. Here is a sandbox for my code:https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-pine-wnsw3